# Проблема с почтой для домена от Яндекса

Tags: debian, email, яндекс-почта

В общем создал я почту для домена благодаря сервису Яндекса. Все прекрасно работает, но есть одно "но". В панели Яндекса у меня создан один почтовый ящик так:

```
support@site.ru
```

Но недавно я заметил, что если я отправляю сообщения с другого ящика себе, но не на созданный в панели `support@site.ru`, а например на `123@site.ru` или `test1@site.ru`,то сообщения все-равно приходят. Получается, что любой спамер не зная моей почты может писать мне?

Записи домена стоят следующие:

```
site.ru. 10800 SOA support.site.ru.
site.ru. 3600 MX mx.yandex.ru.
site.ru. 3600 TXT v=spf1 redirect=_spf.yandex.ru
```

Почту настраивал через ISPmanager. На сервере Debian 8. Использовал инструкцию от Яндекса, даже не знаю где я мог ошибиться.

Comment: [адрес по умолчанию](https://yandex.ru/support/pdd/domain/settings.xml#mail). если в настройках у вас адрес не выбран — обращайтесь в техподдержку.

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его надо адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку.

Comment: благодарю вас. Проблема была именно в адресе по умолчанию.